# Count number of different values in chosen (large) range in VBA?

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel, mergesort

How can I count the number of different values (numbers and strings mixed) in a chosen (large) range in VBA?

I think about this in this way:
 1. Read in data into one dimensional array.
 2. Sort array (quick or merge sort) need to test which
 3. Simply count number of different values if sorted array : `if(a[i]<>a[i+1]) then counter=counter+1`.

Is it the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Edit: I want to do it in Excel.

Comment: You can load the range into a 2D array, then loop though it and use a scripting dictionary to check for uniqueness.  The dictionary has your count when you're done.

Comment: @TimWilliams you beat me to it, exactly my thought :)

Comment: Three answers - nice I will check them and choose one in Friday. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a VBA Solution

You don't need an Array to get this done. You can also use a collection. Example

```
Sub Samples()
    Dim scol As New Collection

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 100 '<~~ Assuming the range is from A1 to A100
            On Error Resume Next
            scol.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Chr(34) & _
            .Range("A" & i).Value & Chr(34)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    Debug.Print scol.Count

    'For Each itm In scol
    '   Debug.Print itm
    'Next
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Sub Samples()
    Dim scol As New Collection
    Dim MyAr As Variant

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        '~~> Select your range in a column here
        MyAr = .Range("A1:A10").Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(MyAr)
            On Error Resume Next
            scol.Add MyAr(i, 1), Chr(34) & _
            MyAr(i, 1) & Chr(34)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    Debug.Print scol.Count

    'For Each itm In scol
    '   Debug.Print itm
    'Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Nice to add that you *don't* need any special libraries to use a `Collection` object, which can make things easier. :-)

Comment: +1 Good answer! It's still slow to iterate over objects (i.e. Range objects) versus arrays, so copying to a variant array and then adding to the collection is *much* faster  (sorry I'm an Excel performance Geek!)

Comment: @i_saw_drones: Yes you are right. The looping was just an example. In real life scenario I would have used an array as in my example above.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of steps 2 and 3, perhaps you could use a `Scripting.Dictionary` and add each value to the dictionary. Any duplicate entries would cause a runtime error which you could either trap or ignore (`resume next`). Finally, you could then just return the dictionary's `count` which would give you the count of unique entries.

Here's a scrap of code I hurriedly threw together:

```
Function UniqueEntryCount(SourceRange As Range) As Long

    Dim MyDataset As Variant
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    MyDataset = SourceRange

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyDataset, 1)

        dic.Add MyDataset(i, 1), ""

    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0

    UniqueEntryCount = dic.Count

    Set dic = Nothing

End Function
```

I know that `resume next` can be considered a 'code smell', but the alternative could be to use the `exists` function of the dictionary to test whether the specified key already exists and then add the value if did not. I just have a feeling that when I did a similar thing in the past that it was faster to just ignore any errors raised for duplicate keys rather than using `exists` YMMY. For completeness, here's the other method using `exists`:

```
Function UniqueEntryCount(SourceRange As Range) As Long

    Dim MyDataset As Variant
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    MyDataset = SourceRange

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyDataset, 1)

        if not dic.Exists(MyDataset(i,1)) then dic.Add MyDataset(i, 1), ""

    Next i

    UniqueEntryCount = dic.Count

    Set dic = Nothing

End Function
```

Whilst the above code is simpler than your proposed method, it would be worth to test the performance of it against your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the idea presented by [i_saw_drones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762259/698590), I strongly recommend the `Scripting.Dictionary`. However, this can be done without `On Error Resume Next` as shown below. Also, his example requires linking the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. My example will demonstrate how to do this without needing to do any linking.

Also, since you're doing this in Excel, then you don't need to create the array in step 1 at all. The function below will accept a range of cells, which will be iterated through completely.

(i.e. `UniqueCount = UniqueEntryCount(ActiveSheet.Cells)` or `UniqueCount = UniqueEntryCount(MySheet.Range("A1:D100")`)

```
Function UniqueEntryCount(SourceRange As Range) As Long
    Dim MyDataset As Variant
    Dim MyRow As Variant
    Dim MyCell As Variant
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim l1 As Long, l2 As Long

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    MyDataset = SourceRange

    For l1 = 1 To UBound(MyDataset)
        ' There is no function to get the UBound of the 2nd dimension 
        ' of an array (that I'm aware of), so use this division to 
        ' get this value. This does not work for >=3 dimensions!
        For l2 = 1 To SourceRange.Count / UBound(MyDataset)
            If Not dic.Exists(MyDataset(l1, l2)) Then
                dic.Add MyDataset(l1, l2), MyDataset(l1, l2)
            End If
        Next l2
    Next l1

    UniqueEntryCount = dic.Count
    Set dic = Nothing
End Function
```

It might also be important to note that the above will count a null string `""` as a distinct value. If you do not want this to be the case, simply change the code to this:

```
    For l1 = 1 To UBound(MyDataset)
        For l2 = 1 To SourceRange.Count / UBound(MyDataset)
            If Not dic.Exists(MyDataset(l1, l2)) And MyDataset(l1, l2) <> "" Then
                dic.Add MyDataset(l1, l2), MyDataset(l1, l2)
            End If
        Next l2
    Next l1
```

Comment: From a performance point of view, I would not recommend iterating through every cell (i.e. object) and performing an implicit type coercion to variant, as looping through objects is computationally expensive. This is why it is more performant to coerce it to an array and loop through the array. Microsoft also recommend this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673.aspx - section entitled "Read and Write Large Blocks of Data in a Single Operation"

Comment: @i_saw_drones I agree. :-) I just thought I'd throw it out there as an option. I also wanted to plagiarize you as little as possible. ;-)

Comment: @i_saw_drones Yes, you can perform the 2D array coercion, which can be done within my version of your function (updated my answer), rather than having to pass a 1D array/range to the function.

Comment: Good point and good idea :) Nice answer! BTW UBound accepts an extra parameter for the dimension you wish to find the upper bound for (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278658.aspx)

Comment: @i_saw_drones I saw you do that, but I didn't know what it was. Shame on me for not researching better. ;-) At least now I know. Thanks! Then of course, you can expand that to a >=3D array very simply.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is written in C#. This is how I would do it.

```
// first copy the array so you don't lose any data
List<value> copiedList = new List<value>(yourArray.ToList());

//for through your list so you test every value
for (int a = 0; a < copiedList.Count; a++)
{
  // copy instances to a new list so you can count the values and do something with them
  List<value> subList = new List<value>(copiedList.FindAll(v => v == copiedList[i]);

  // do not do anything if there is only 1 value found
  if(subList.Count > 1)
                        // You would want to leave 1 'duplicate' in
    for (int i = 0; i < subList.Count - 1; i++)
        // remove every instance from the array but one
        copiedList.Remove(subList[i]);
}
int count = copiedList.Count; //this is your actual count
```

Have not tested it, please try.

You should wrap this inside a method so there is no messing around with the garbage. Otherwise you would lose the copy of the array only later. (return count)

EDIT: You need a list for this to work, use Array.ToList();

Comment: if (subArray.count > 1) check is not necessary, the for loop accounts for it.

Comment: How does answering a VBA question in C# help? ;)

Comment: And if the user doesn't know c# then how will that help?

Comment: I agree with @SiddharthRout. Not all languages have the same features so a C# answer to be translated is not very helpful.